# Eclipse Android Mac 10.4 problem, dyld: Symbol not found: _open$UNIX2003

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I have just set up the Eclipse Android SDK environment. I tried creating a basic HelloWorld app by following this page http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html

As soon as I set up the project i get get this error in the console

[2010-06-09 23:12:22 - Helloworld] dyld: Symbol not found: _open$UNIX2003
[2010-06-09 23:12:22 - Helloworld]   Referenced from: /usr/lib/android-sdk-mac_86/platforms/android-3/tools/aapt
[2010-06-09 23:12:22 - Helloworld]   Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
[2010-06-09 23:12:22 - Helloworld]

Is it something to do do with my MacOS version ?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this usually means that you are trying to link object code produced using different versions of gcc and/or different SDK versions. You might need to rebuild one or more libraries.